# CSS: stretch div to 100% except some fluid part

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="left" style="height:30%;background-color: cyan;">           
        </div>
        <div id="right" style="height:30%;background-color: yellow">
            <a style="padding: 3em;margin: 3em;" >test</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I stretch div (id=left) to 100% but except the width of div (id=right). I mean left div width + right div width must be equal to 100% of the window.

Comment: u either give `width: 50%` for both or put them in one div and give them `width: 100%` ,also don't use the table tags ,use the css props instead ,u will get a much better result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch them in the HTML, first put there the `#right`, then `#left`.

Add `float` to `#right`, it will have the width of its content and `#left` takes the rest of window width as its width.

```
<style>
#right {float: right;}
#left {overflow: hidden}
</style>

<div id="right" style="height:30%;background-color: yellow">
    <a style="padding: 3em;margin: 3em;" >test</a>
</div>

<div id="left" style="height:30%;background-color: cyan;">xxx</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9nqme599/2/

Comment: Note:+ #left{overflow:hidden;}

Comment: Wellcome. Could you take a look at the similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885991/css-set-width-of-absolute-div-to-100-minus-width-of-fluid-div

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
     <body>
         <div id="left" style="height:30%;background-color: cyan;">           
         </div>
         <div id="right" style="height:30%;background-color: yellow;float: right;">
             <a style="padding: 3em;margin: 3em;" >test</a>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```